# Laravel, nginx, Docker, PHP - Load Test, Very Unsatisfactory Results

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm, load-testing, hetzner

We are creating two servers in Hetzner (https://www.hetzner.com/cloud).

Parmeters of both:
`CPX51 - vCPU 16 AMD, RAM 32 GB`.

On one server with `Ubuntu 22.04` we install `Docker` and run the PHP application Laravel + nginx on it. The nginx image is https://serversideup.net/open-source/docker-php/.

On the other one we install the `Artillery` application (https://www.artillery.io)

Our test scenario

```
config:
  target: "https://IP"
  tls: {
      "rejectUnauthorized": false
  }
  phases:
    - duration: 60
      name: "1000 on 60 sec"
      arrivalCount: 1000
    - duration: 60
      name: "2000 on 60 sec"
      arrivalCount: 2000
    - duration: 60
      name: "5000 on 60 sec"
      arrivalCount: 5000
    - duration: 60
      name: "10000 on 60 sec"
      arrivalCount: 10000
    - duration: 60
      name: "15000 on 60 sec"
      arrivalCount: 15000
    - duration: 60
      name: "20000 on 60 sec"
      arrivalCount: 20000
scenarios:
  - name: Main
    flow:
      - get:
          url: "/"
```

Our result is:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnKjC.png)

The results seem poor to us, especially reading articles like this (https://reviewsignal.com/blog/2014/06/25/40-million-hits-a-day-on-wordpress-using-a-10-vps/).
Our portal will be hosted on Kubernetes with LoadBalancer at the end.
However, we would like to know which results on such a machine are good and which are bad. We cannot find such a reference anywhere. We are looking for some sort of comparison.
Can you help us?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying any Nginx configuration from the article you "read" in particular or any [Nginx high-load configuration](https://www.plesk.com/blog/various/nginx-performance-tuning-tips/) in general?

Have you did the same on [Laravel side](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/optimize-laravel/)?

If you're using a database (and I believe you are) have you walked through database vendor's recommendations on its performance and tuning?

Also your test doesn't make a lot of sense as I don't think hammering the IP address of your endpoint is a valid use case for your application, even if it's a one-pager or [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) it will contain images, scripts, styles, etc. which should also be downloaded. And if your application assumes more complex logic, user journeys, etc. - you should replicate real user actions with 100% accuracy and you might need a more advanced performance testing tool like [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) which can be [configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is there any table/comparison/indicator that tells how many users/requests per minute is Heavy Load? We are creating a startup with a small team. We don't know what kind of traffic to expect. What score of users/requests in nginx per minute is a good score for one instance?